# NaN returns matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following code;

```
x = -12:1/32:12;
y = -12:1/32:12;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

z = (sin(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)))/(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2))
```

For some reason it always returns NaN and I don't get it if I make

```
z = (sin(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)))
```

I actually get numbers. What is the problem?

Comment: Replace `/` with [`./`](https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are after:

```
z = (sin(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)))./(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2));
```

which element-wise division rather than matrix division.